# Как получить данные facebook по кнопке, чтобы после получения произошел logout

Tags: javascript, facebook, facebook-api, facebook-graph-api

Имею следующую кнопку

```
<div class="fb-login-button"
   data-max-rows="1"
   data-size="large"
   data-button-type="login_with"
   data-show-faces="false"
   data-auto-logout-link="true"
   data-use-continue-as="false"
   id="fb-btn"
></div>
```

И JS код, который автоматически проверяет вошел ли пользователь на фейсбук при каждой загрузке страницы и отправляет мне данные.

```
const $facebookBtn = $('#fb-btn');

$facebookBtn.on('login', this.getDataUserFacebook());

getDataUserFacebook() {
    FB.login(response => {
      if (response.status !== 'connected') {
        console.log(`Not auth, status ${response.status}`);
      }

      FB.api('/me?fields=link,id,name,email,birthday,location', (response) => {
        this.buildProfile(response);
      });
    });
  }

  buildProfile(user) {
    this.user = {
      profile_link: user.link,
      name: user.name,
      birthday: user.birthday,
    };

    console.log(this.user);
  }
```

Мне необходимо, чтобы никогда пользователь не имел возможности сразу быть вошедшим через facebook. Мне просто нужно, чтобы по клику "Войти через FB" вызывалось окно доступа к приложению, дальше формировался нужный мне объект, а затем происходил выход. А сейчас у меня происходит не по клику, а автоматически. Что я делаю не так?

Comment: По всей вероятности вы уже один раз подтвердили доступ facebook application к вашим данным, вот пока сессия у вас в браузере есть, он и атоматически проходит дальше. Откройте браузер в инкогнито и ещё раз попробуйте.

Comment: @Арсен спасибо за ответ. Но проблема не в этом. А в том, что у меня сразу выскакивает окно авторизации, а не по клику. Даже в режиме инкогнито

Comment: Попробуйте удалить первые две строки в коде и поставьте самому обработчик, при нажатии которого вызовите метод getDataUserFacebook()